# how to put current location coordinate to google maps api (camera)

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am using google map api in my app and I want when run my code show me my location automatic in view.
I write my code and run but my code not working and I understand that my location method don't save my coordinate location in two variable.why???

please guide me about it.

```
    @implementation ViewController
    {
        double latitudes;
        double longitudes;
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
        GMSMapView *mapView_;
    }
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self GetMyLocation];

        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the

//my friend I don't know why my two variable (latitudes,longitudes) 
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitudes longitude:longitudes zoom:14];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero  camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        [mapView_ setMapType:kGMSTypeNormal];
    }
    - (void) GetMyLocation{
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            longitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
            latitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        }
    }
    @end
```

Comment: where u checked in simulator or device

Comment: Reason why its not updating is because your trying to set new GMSCameraPosition when CLLocationManager hasn't updated it location yet. Make the update camera call in your didUpdateToLocation method as its when the object found its current coordinates

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I check on device

Comment: @ShamsAhmed my friend please guide me and tell me with code...

Comment: what the problem u  meet

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I want set camera position with my location coordinate but my code not working!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
 @implementation ViewController
    {
        double latitudes;
        double longitudes;
        CLLocationManager *locationManager;
        GMSMapView *mapView_;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [self GetMyLocation];

        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the

//my friend I don't know why my two variable (latitudes,longitudes) 
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0 longitude:0 zoom:14];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.frame  camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        [mapView_ setMapType:kGMSTypeNormal];
        [self.view addSubView:mapView_];
    }

    - (void) GetMyLocation{
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            longitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
            latitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        }

        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude zoom:14];

        [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: my friend this code is not working because don't add mapView_ to view

Comment: where I add my mapView_?

Comment: add it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear

Comment: my dude mapView_ is GMSMapView class and I don't add to self.view is not working but when I write self.view = mapView_ is working!!! but I want to use mapView_ in viewDidLoad method and when I add this to view I can't use mapView_ in viewDidLoad!!! why???

Comment: Sorry my previous code wasn't clear, this new update should work.